# Changing array shape in a compound type

Tags: c++, hdf5

I'm starting from a struct

```
typedef struct SpikeInfo {
        uint64 timestamp;
        int recording;
        int16 waveform[MAX_TRANSFORM_SIZE];
    } SpikeInfo;
```

and then I create a HDF5 compound datatype:

```
CompType spiketype(sizeof(SpikeInfo));
hsize_t dims[2] = {MAX_TRANSFORM_SIZE/nChannels, nChannels};
spiketype.insertMember(H5std_string("waveform"), HOFFSET(SpikeInfo, waveform), ArrayType(getNativeType(I16), 2, dims));
spiketype.insertMember(H5std_string("recording"), HOFFSET(SpikeInfo, recording), getNativeType(U16));
spiketype.insertMember(H5std_string("timestamp"), HOFFSET(SpikeInfo, timestamp), getNativeType(U64));
```

Thus the array has allocated `MAX_TRANSFORM_SIZE/nChannels` rows. However, it's most likely that I will be constantly receiving less data (for example with the number of rows being  onlyhalf of `MAX_TRANSFORM_SIZE/nChannels`), and then I end up having to fill the rest with zeros, which unnecessarily increases the filesize. I was wondering if there's a way to make that `ArrayType` resizable, so that I can make it bigger if it's necessary, but it's small at first.

I know there is a type VarLenType, but the documentation doesn't show any useful methods for it. Is such a thing possible at all?

Comment: I don't mean storing the data in memory, but saving it to a file. If the the row dimensions is bigger than of the data that I have, then I will have unfilled entries in the file. ArrayType refers to a HDF5 datatype, and I want to make that resizable. I know you can make datasets extensible, but can you do the same with datatypes?